# Rotate Image on hover and prevent it from returning back

Tags: html, css, rotation

I Wanted a image to rotate when ever someone hoers over it and i succedded but when I I mouse out the image returns back to it's original position i don't want it to return to origional position i have used the following code

```
  <style>
.rotate{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;

    overflow:hidden;

    }   

.rotate:hover   
{ 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}   
</style>



</head>




<body>
<br><br><br>

<img src="./rotate_files/1.png" class="rotate">
<img src="./rotate_files/2.png" class="rotate">
<img src="./rotate_files/3.png" class="rotate">
<img src="./rotate_files/4.png" class="rotate">
<img src="./rotate_files/5.png" class="rotate">





</body></html>
```

Comment: Use Javascript to add a class to make it stay that way.

Comment: CAn't I don't know javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way you can do it. You need to use jquery for this.

**HTML:**

```
<img src="./rotate_files/1.png" class="rotate">
<img src="./rotate_files/2.png" class="rotate">
<img src="./rotate_files/3.png" class="rotate">
<img src="./rotate_files/4.png" class="rotate">
<img src="./rotate_files/5.png" class="rotate">
```

**CSS:**

```
 .rotate{
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
transition-duration: 0.8s;

-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
-o-transition-property: -o-transform;
transition-property: transform;

overflow:hidden;

}   

.hoverstyle  
{ 
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(360deg); 
-o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('img').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hoverstyle');
});
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAaPu/61/)

Comment: HEy I tried your code and it perfectly works but dude when i hover again on the same image nothing happen please help and also explain the jquery thanks in advance

Comment: what you want to do in the next hover? In jquery, I just adding one class when you hover on image. In that class i have added your rotation css. thats it.